# django handling request and scheduling code

Tags: python, django

```
def index(request):
  # this function take request from extension and scrape the link provided in post request


def job():
  # take link from database scrape it and again store in database
  # this function is called by schedluler
```

I want to do the both task at the same time

problem :- when i start django server it goes in infinite loop of  scheduler part and not able to handle post request

Comment: Sounds like your searching for multiprocessing tools? Check the details about MP [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process). Also, finish the tour and you'll understand that you've got to show more effort to prevent a down-vote frenzy on the question.

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond    during sending email through python code  i tried two thing 1)enable less secure app and firewall off

Comment: Without any actual code in your question to verify by any of us it becomes useless to spam your time-out error in a comment. Perhaps you can post that and place your error beneith it using > to get it inside the yellow box?

Comment: Unless you explain your problem in more details, what you have tried, how it failed, your question will get flagged and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing a scheduler is a pretty daunting task. Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the facilities of your operating system to call into your application. For instance, almost every Unix system has `cron` or `atd` that will let you run commands at a known interval.

Alternatively, you may use a library such as [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). It is designed as a task queue, for executing tasks asynchronously and retrieving results later. It includes a cron-like task scheduler.

Comment: TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond    during sending email through python code  i tried two thing 1)enable less secure app and firewall off